# CP2102 with 3V Arduino and hardware

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, cp2102

My harware set up is: Arduino pro mini and nrf24l01 wireless module. This hardware is supplied by stabilized 3V generated by LDO from 1s li-pol. I need serial communication for debugging purposes, but I was wondering if connecting CP2102 to this harware set up does not damage the nrf24l01 module, which has max 3.6V VCC. Is it safe to use CP2102 with 3V supply from its regulator to my board, or not? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean that you have 3.3 V on your Arduino. 3 V would be a bit too low.

Information that can be obtained from the datasheets:

- NRF23l01 is 5 V tolerant on the datalines. Good to know but doesn't matter in this case
- CP2102 has onboard 3.3 V
  regulator and outputs 3.3 V levels.

So it seems safe to use it with the system. Make sure to connect the GND of the CP2102 with the device you're talking to.

From CP2102 datasheet:

[image]